# clickable listview for all subItem in its item c#

Tags: c#, listview, click

i am making listview of many column and i want to make the list clickable in all the subitem like the picture below.

[image]

However, what i get is like the picture below.

[image]

this is my code:

```
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewItem listviewitem;

            listviewitem = new ListViewItem("John");
            listviewitem.SubItems.Add("Smith");
            listviewitem.SubItems.Add("kaya");
            listviewitem.SubItems.Add("bun");
            this.listView1.Items.Add(listviewitem);
            this.listView1.ColumnClick += new ColumnClickEventHandler(ColumnClick);
//show header
            listView1.View = View.Details;

            // Loop through and size each column header to fit the column header text.
            foreach (ColumnHeader ch in this.listView1.Columns)
            {
                ch.Width = -2;
            }
}
```

this is my columnclick event handler.

```
 // ColumnClick event handler.
    private void ColumnClick(object o, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set the ListViewItemSorter property to a new ListViewItemComparer 
        // object. Setting this property immediately sorts the 
        // ListView using the ListViewItemComparer object.
        this.listView1.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer(e.Column);
    }




    }
class ListViewItemComparer : IComparer
{
    private int col;
    public ListViewItemComparer()
    {
        col = 0;
    }
    public ListViewItemComparer(int column)
    {
        col = column;
    }
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return String.Compare(((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[col].Text, ((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[col].Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the first picture from?  It doesn't look like a winform at all.  Are you trying to get WPF functionality in a winform?

Comment: Assuming that you are referring to in-place editing, you should use a third-party control like those offered by [DevExpress](http://devexpress.com) or [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com).

Comment: You might want to looking into telerik

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
```